# How can I scale a UIElement in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, scale, uielement

I have defined a canvas in XAML that I add a lot of figures to in C#. I've got some pinch going on but need some help applying the scale to the `UIElement`.

I've created my `ScaleTransform` like this:

```
ScaleTransform scaleTrans = new ScaleTransform();
scaleTrans.ScaleX = scaleFactor;
scaleTrans.ScaleY = scaleFactor;
```

But how can I apply it to my `UIElement` (the only children of my canvas)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the  [UIElement.RenderTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx) property :

```
yourElement.RenderTransform = scaleTrans;
```